# mscorlib.dll namespace is not working in Windows Phone 8.1 XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a code in WP8.0 as below

```
 xmlns:my="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

 <my:String x:Key="OnlineImagesPageName">OnlineImages</my:String>
 <my:Int32 x:Key="PeopleInsertLimit">5</my:Int32>
 <my:Int32 x:Key="ShowsInsertLimit">2</my:Int32>
```

but when i use this snippet in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal Apps, the "String" is not showing when i write

```
<my:
```

in the code, how to resolve this .

Any NameSpace to be changed, Guide me in resolvng this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the version I use in universal

xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

```
 <x:String>11</x:String>
    <x:Bind></x:Bind>
    <x:Boolean>true</x:Boolean>
    <x:Double>1</x:Double>
    <x:Int32>1</x:Int32>
    <x:NullExtension></x:NullExtension>
```

Depending on the target it has changed with the history of XAML